# integer index incrementation in array

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, integer

I have one doubt in the following snippet. Actually I am initializing all the array index to zero in following code, but this `for` loop is going infinitely. I found reason that we are trying to access the 26th index of array, so that value gets initialized to zero again since there is 0 to 25 index. So the for loop is going infinitely. Explain if any one the actual reason behind this stuff.

```
int array[26];
int i; 
for (i = 0; i <= 26; i++) 
    array[i]= 0;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `i < 26`; otherwise you exceed the array bounds.

Due to the layout of the stack on most systems `array[26]` will point to the memory used for `i` which results in the loop starting again since you loop body is setting i to 0 instead of an appropriate array element.

Note that you can simply use `int array[36] = { 0 };` to create the array with all elements being set to 0.

Comment: when we are exceeding index , it suppose to change index values not the i value. it seems to be very weired thing. if some body use unknowingly for some other purpose not to  initialize . it can big make damage.

Comment: Well you write to a memory location outside of the array. Obviously there is *something* at this location - and as I said, usually it's the var defined after the array.

Comment: @pavun_cool: Yes, it can "make big damage". You must be careful not to write past the end of a buffer. This is the cause of a tremendous number of bugs in the software world, some of which have caused space rockets to explode. Welcome to low-level programming.

Comment: You could run your program through [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) - it usually detects problems like off-by-ones or plain invalid memory accesses and shows you a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `i` is located after `array` in the memory and it become `0` when `i=26` in the loop. I.e. `&array[26] == &i`.

Answer (score 0):

> I found reason that we are trying to access the 26th index of array, so that value gets initialized to zero again since there is 0 to 25 index. So the for loop is going infinitely.

The reason is that your loop variable `i` goes from `0` to `26` *inclusive*. But there is no `array[26]`.. only `array[0]` to `array[25]` (which is a total of 26 elements).

You are invoking undefined behaviour by writing to `array[26]`; it *just so happens* in your execution run that `i` was laid out just after `array` in memory, and you were accidentally writing `0` to `i` due to the erroneous write. This may have caused an infinite loop.

Instead write:

```
int array[26];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
   array[i] = 0; 
}
```